# Revit API 2012 Event handler for Cancel and Finish buttons

Tags: c#, events, revit-api

I need events to catch the finish and cancel buttons in Revit when creating a model group, or a Floor for example. The image below shows the buttons. Are there events for these actions?

[image: Revit 2012 Buttons]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I guess at least the Finish button will raise the Document_Changed event and maybe you can get name of the transaction to narrow down the action you really want.

Comment: You are correct about the finish button. Thank you very much. Now all I have to do is figure out which event is raised when the cancel button is pressed.